# How to Debug HTML5 extensions for InDesign CC?

Tags: debugging, adobe, remote-debugging, adobe-indesign

Currently i'm in the process of getting to know InDesign CC HTML5 extensions. 
Using the Extension Builder plugin for eclipse did a few tests creating extensions. No problem there.
But when it came to debugging i ran into some problems. First problem was finding a way to debug at all.

After some research i stumbled over this [short guide to HTML5 extensions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/creativesuite/articles/a-short-guide-to-HTML5-extensions.html). It contains a guide for debugging which i followed meticulously.

But now when it comes down to actually debugging no debugging view opens nor am i able to connect to the application via chrome for remote debugging.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you cannot use the `Run As/Debug As -> Adobe InDesign Extension` of eclipse to start the extension for debugging, because the essential `.debug`-file will not be exported.

So everytime you want to debug something first `Run As -> Adobe InDesign Extension` and then copy the `.debug`-file into: 
"$User$\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CEPServiceManager4\extensions\$extesion folder$" (Windows)

After that restart InDesign **MANUALLY** (not from eclipse that is) and connect via 
`"localhost:$port specified in .debug$"` (works only) with chrome to your extension.

This is not very ellegant but it works, at least for me.